# Setting up rtsp stream on Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, rtsp

I am trying to set up an rtsp stream that can be accessed from an application. I have been experimenting with ffmpeg to realize that. I have succeded as far as I was able to stream from ffmpeg to ffplay but I could not load the stream in vlc for example. Here are the calls that I did from two different shells on the same machine:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -loop 1 -r 24 -i test_1.jpg -vcodec libx264 -tune stillimage -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:1234/stream.sdp

ffplay.exe -rtsp_flags listen rtsp://127.0.0.1:1234/stream.sdp
```

Can anybody explain to me what I would have to do to load the stream as a network stream using vlc? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before and I'm not sure what was wrong with rtsp output of ffmpeg. But what i can say right now is please consider using Live555 library if you have any streaming scenario. cause the ffmpeg code (for rtp muxer) is not good and it is buggy. ffmpeg has another solution for streaming server which is called ffserver which prepare ffmpeg pipe for vlc or another third-party application. and that's bad written and buggy too (libav group -another fork of libav* libraries) never used ffserver code and in not sure if they have any plan to consider ffserver as their solution. they have ffplay(avplay), ffmpeg(avconv) and ffprobe but not ffserver.

If you want to use Live555 which really easy, you have to just go to their website (www.live555.com) download the source code and build MediaServer application (It is in 'MediaServer' folder). if you read the code's documentation, I'm sure you will have not any problem.It's a basic rtsp server to stream any (supported) accessible file on your HDD via rtsp url of your server.
if you have any problem with code just comment here, so I can help you more with live555.

Comment: I mark your answer as correct. I will probably use vlc now instead of ffmpeg so I most probably will not try Live555. If I do I might ask you again for some support. Thanks!